# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'BUE' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Trying to run this query I wrote to return a list of files in a course, but running into this error that a conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'BUE' to data type int.

```
select 
  (CASE
    WHEN isnull (Search_Hotel . ExFull. value ('(//Hotel/@source)[1]' , 'varchar(10)'), '' )='YCIX' 
    THEN Search_Hotel.ExFull.value('data(//Hotel/@city)[1]','int')
    WHEN isnull (Search_Hotel . ExFull. value ('(//HotelBeds/ServiceHotel/@type)[1]' , 'varchar(20)'), '' )='ServiceHotel' 
    THEN 'BUE'
    ELSE
    0 -- Sin  identificable             
    END ),
* from 
FileService
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select 
  (CASE
    WHEN isnull (Search_Hotel . ExFull. value ('(//Hotel/@source)[1]' , 'varchar(10)'), '' )='YCIX' 
    THEN Search_Hotel.ExFull.value('data(//Hotel/@city)[1]','varchar(10)')
    WHEN isnull (Search_Hotel . ExFull. value ('(//HotelBeds/ServiceHotel/@type)[1]' , 'varchar(20)'), '' )='ServiceHotel' 
    THEN 'BUE'
    ELSE
    '0' -- Sin  identificable             
    END ),
* from 
FileService
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias. Soy muy despistado.